# How do i even out the lighting in colored images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on an image filter but for that to work out properly I need to even the lightning in the image. [Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Cw8.jpg) | [Output Image Due to a lighting issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDQoL.jpg) | [Output when lightning is same all over the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrT7U.jpg)
I have tried this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('new_sample/sample6.jpg', 1)
original = img.copy()
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
l, a, b = cv2.split(lab)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=4.0, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
cl = clahe.apply(l)
limg = cv2.merge((cl, a, b))
final = cv2.cvtColor(limg, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
kernel_sharpen_3 = np.array([[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]                      
    [-1, 2, 2, 2, -1],
    [-1, 2, 8, 2, -1],
    [-1, 2, 2, 2, -1],
    [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]) / 8
img = cv2.filter2D(final, -1, kernel_sharpen_3)
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img, 110, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
threshold = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(thresh1, 11, 31, 9) 
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(threshold, (5, 5), 0)
stack_horizontal = np.concatenate((original, final), axis=1)
stack_horizontal2 = np.concatenate((threshold, blur), axis=1)
stack_vertical = np.concatenate((stack_horizontal, stack_horizontal2), 
axis=0)
cv2.imshow('Images', cv2.resize(stack_vertical, (700, 1000)))
cv2.imwrite("magic.jpg", blur)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Use Adaptive Thresholding or Otsu's Binarization

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea in Python/OpenCV. Do adaptive thresholding and then colorize the white with the average color of the original.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("purple_text.jpg")
h, w, c = img.shape

# get average color of img
color = cv2.mean(img)[0:3]

# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# do adaptive threshold on gray image
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 21, 13)
thresh3 = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# change white to color
result1 = thresh3.copy()
result1[thresh==255] = color

# optionally colorize text darker and more blue
result2 = result1.copy()
result2[thresh==0] = (color[0],0.65*color[1],0.65*color[2])

# write results to disk
cv2.imwrite("purple_text_processed1.jpg", result1)
cv2.imwrite("purple_text_processed2.jpg", result2)

# display it
cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.imshow("THRESHOLD", thresh)
cv2.imshow("RESULT1", result1)
cv2.imshow("RESULT2", result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Background Colorized:

[image]

Background and Text Colorized:

[image]

**ADDITION:**

Here is a better variation that gets the average color of the background as well as the text and colorizes one or both of them from the adaptive threshold.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("purple_text.jpg")
h, w, c = img.shape

# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# do adaptive threshold on gray image to make a mask
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 21, 13)

# get color of image where thresh is 255
bgcolor = cv2.mean(img, thresh)[0:3]

# get color where thresh is 0
textcolor = cv2.mean(img, 255-thresh)[0:3]

# put colorize background and text with bgcolor and color, resp.
result = img.copy()
result[thresh==255] = bgcolor
result[thresh==0] = textcolor

# write results to disk
cv2.imwrite("purple_text_processed3.jpg", result)

# optionally darken text COLOR_BGR2GRAY
resultx = img.copy()
resultx[thresh==255] = bgcolor
resultx[thresh==0] = (0.75*textcolor[0], 0.75*textcolor[1], 0.75*textcolor[2])

# write results to disk
cv2.imwrite("purple_text_processed3x.jpg", resultx)

# display it
#cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.imshow("THRESHOLD", thresh)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.imshow("RESULTX", resultx)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Colorized Text and Background:

[image]

Colorized and Darkened Text and Background:

[image]

Comment: its working on simple documents but documents with images or posters its not working well.  example :  https://drive.google.com/open?id=164c6ifFLyAeJU9t3-kfVM9C5Ahiy7PAs   output: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uj2SE4uJoUyjVqisAfBZZ2mxA9Brk06

Comment: `@Naman Gupta. For images with detailed backgrounds, it is much harder. Perhaps adaptive histogram equalization might help. Another idea would be NASA Retinex -  https://dragon.larc.nasa.gov. But you would have to script that in OpenCV. However, the linked image that you provided does not seem to me to have non-uniform background lighting. It is just a little too dark. So you should be able to brighten it. You can use the following technique. Just set your desired brightness and contrast as mean and standard deviation. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/

Answer (score 0):

Try the bellow code. if not good then try Otsu's Binarization.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('bookpage.jpg')
th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(grayscaled, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 115, 1)
cv2.imshow('original',img)
cv2.imshow('Adaptive threshold',th)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```